# Services on the same network cannot be seen by alias, only by ip

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `bridge` network locally:

```bash
$ docker network ls

NETWORK ID     NAME                             DRIVER    SCOPE
08e7e0710fd9   bridge                           bridge    local
```

I have 3 containers linked in this network:

```bash
$ docker network inspect bridge

"Containers": {
            "0b76b1bb23bf805b181ee1696d1366f35e5f49df446203deb32f13bd2caaba32": {
                "Name": "local-mysql",
                "EndpointID": "0288da5e7374456d8c877a8230e9515a63799bfe20f1081ac03003cfab8e0f59",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "340c09255c23104e1b52f6b6b2f1adbb4ce6d5a0a139e8ec4ac613198a853022": {
                "Name": "local-app",
                "EndpointID": "dedccf1c9830cb2e28e2ac3e3953c73006e1294b45a3f70475d01a918787c03c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ccabe6e1231144b023ddfd49403f63c49de03747ce4c31f8b55533c5b5c69f91": {
                "Name": "local-phpmyadmin",
                "EndpointID": "3f13e0677c07da79df6b7ad32038b437619250c38d4d82656b3aa7dbc0aaebe2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

I have the following containers running:

```bash
$ docker container ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                       NAMES
a4395f3e72f6   local-php-app           "docker-php-entrypoi…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                                        local-php-app
ccabe6e12311   local-phpmyadmin        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:3305->80/tcp                                                        local-phpmyadmin
0b76b1bb23bf   local-mysql             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                           local-mysql
340c09255c23   local-app               "/core/run.sh"           4 hours ago      Up 26 minutes   0.0.0.0:15384->5005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20069->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:19286->8443/tcp   local-app
```

Python code trying to connect:

```py
        mysql_pass = ''
        mysql_endpoint = 'local-mysql:3306'

        mysql_host = mysql_endpoint.split(":")[0] 
        mysql_port = int(mysql_endpoint.split(":")[1]) 
        mysql_db = "localdb"
        mysql_user = 'root'
        
        db_connection = pymysql.connect(host=mysql_host, 
                                        port=mysql_port, 
                                        user=mysql_user, 
                                        passwd=mysql_pass, 
                                        db=mysql_db)
```

So using `mysql_endpoint="local-mysql:3306"`, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'local-mysql' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
```

So I decided to get the `local-mysql` container IP to use directly:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 0b76b1bb23bf
        
172.17.0.3
```

If I change it to `mysql_endpoint="172.17.0.3:3306"`, it works perfectly:

```
"Database version: ('8.0.31',)"
```

Why?

The fact that they are all on the same network should already be possible to make the connection using the "service name"?

What's the difference between using `"alias"` and using `IP`?

How do I use "links" when I have services with different "docker-compose.yml"?

Comment: What is `nans-mentor-mysql` from the error message?  Did you `docker network create` a network; how did you start these containers so they're all attached to the same network?  You shouldn't use links at all, they're considered obsolete at this point.

Comment: I corrected the name, `nans-mentor-mysql` was my other local example, changed it to `local-mysql`. ## 

I didn't create the network, bridge is already a standard docker network, I was using it.  ##

Yes, all containers are on the same network, as we can see in the json listed above. ## 

About links, how do I use links when referring to different `docker-compose.yml` services?

Comment: See [@BMitch's answer to your other question](/a/74903410) – the `bridge` network is an obsolete setup from first-generation Docker networking that remains the `docker run` default for compatibility reasons, and it is not a "Docker network" in the way you're expecting here.